# Variable as a part of a global constant

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular project, a global path constant is declared in the service.
This path is used to config one of the modules in the imports in app.module.ts file:

```
export const PATH = 'https://website.com:4200/?query=query_params';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService {...}
```

The same service has a method that receives the necessary query parameters from the server.
How can I insert query parameters into this constant?

Something like this as in a simple class:

```
export let PATH = `https://website.com:4200/?query=${ getParams() }`;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService {
   getParams(): string {
      return 'some_params';
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything and had it not work? You at least recognize that it's no longer a constant if you're able to stick variables in it.

Comment: Of course, if it is possible to change it, then it will not be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically what you put into your environment files.

Then, usually, what you do in your services is this

```js
getSomething() {
  const url = `${environment.path}?query=${yourQueryVariable}`;
  return this.http.get<any>(url);
}
```

The great thing about Angular is that almost any common task is already well thought and documented, try sticking to it and you'll see amazing productivity results !